# How do I include another column without having to place it in the GROUP BY Clause? [SQL Server 2005]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I use this query below to get the latest Serial Number that has been added

```
SELECT 
    SerialNo, 
    MAX(AddDate) AS AddDate
FROM 
    tst_EquipmentItem 
WHERE 
    ControlNo = 'TM-00012'
GROUP BY 
    SerialNo
ORDER BY 
    AddDate
```

```
OUTPUT:
SerialNo////AddDate
=======================================
TM-00012////2008-08-05 10:25:00.000
```

Now in the tst_Equipment table there is a ControlNo column. If I include ControlNo to the above statement I get a different output

```
OUTPUT
SerialNo///ControlNo///AddDate
====================================================
TM-00012///TM-CGI-F-0027///2004-02-09 08:20:00.000
TM-00012///TM-EN-N-0068///2008-08-05 10:25:00.000
```

How do I include the ControlNo column without having to put it in the GROUP BY Clause so that I can get the latest ControlNo for each SerialNo?

Comment: May I ask why without putting `ControlNo` into `group by` section? What is your expected result?

Comment: Because I get two different numbers instead of just the getting the latest one

Comment: Can you check my answer then and tell whether is ok or not (according to your expectations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your data, I would do:

```
select distinct t.serialNo, e.controlNo, t.addDate
from tst_EquipmentItem e
join (
    select serialNo, max(addDate) as addDate
    from tst_EquipmentItem 
    group by serialNo
) t on t.serialNo = e.serialNo and t.addDate = e.addDate
```

Comment: This. But I also Included addDate to link them together; now I get the output I need!

Comment: @Kurusu and that is my [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8613588/1), I'll rollback to that revision :-).

Comment: this is the same as

select t.serialNo, Max(t.controlNo), max(t.addDate)
from tst_EquipmentItem e
GROUP BY t.serialNo

unless your controlno is not incremental (i.e. the latest one may not be the highest number)

Answer (score 1):

It either has to be in the group by clause or be part of a computed value. , example

```
SUM(ControlNo), MAX(ControlNo), MIN(ControlNo).
```

I would suggest max in your case, assuming that the numbers increment.

Comment: I don't think I can use SUM() because its datatype is varchar, and MAX() doesn't seem to work either

Comment: then put it in group by clause

Comment: yeah the sum was just there as an example of different functions you can use instead of group by.